# gradle.properties special characters in proxy password

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle.properties

I just can't get to work gradle with my corporate proxy.
I got it to work though with node.js in the .npmrc file.

My password has a "**<**" character in the password. In the .npmrc file I had to escape it by writing "**%3C**" instead:

```
proxy=http://na_me:123%3C456@proxy.net:80/
https-proxy=http://na_me:123%3C456@proxy.net:80/
```

My gradle.properties look like this:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=proxy.net
systemProp.http.proxyPort=80
systemProp.http.proxyUser=na_me
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=123<456
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=localhost

systemProp.https.proxyHost=proxy.net
systemProp.https.proxyPort=80
systemProp.https.proxyUser=na_me
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=123<456
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=localhost
```

Is that syntax correct in theory? Or do I have to escape anything like the "**<**"?

I always get the error:

```
Error: Unable to tunnel through proxy. 
Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required"
```

I tried using the global gradle.properties file in my user folder and also creating the file in C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle.

Comment: I think it should be ok. The point is, you failed to state what your problem / error is. Do you get an error message? Does it just not use the proxy? ...?

Comment: I totally forgot, I always get a 407 error: proxy authentication required.

Comment: Afair with a wrong password it should be 401, so I'd say it is not a wrong password. Actually this is probably also not a Gradle problem, afair those properties are handled by core Java code and not by Gradle itself.

Comment: It's weird, it looks like it won't even use the proxy settings. Do you have any suggestions what I could try? Android Studio has its own proxy settings, and they work perfectly. It's just gradle everytime.

Comment: Start Wireshark and look at the network traffic?

Comment: Did you find the solution to this by any chance?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't remember the solution to the whole proxy issue in the end. But I can tell you that the character escaping was not the issue. The syntax in my post is correct as posted.